# SVG <image> turn off interpolation?

Tags: image, svg, interpolation

I have a 3x3 PNG embedded image (colors are white-black-red-green-yellow-blue-magenta-cyan-white) that I want to display over a larger area without interpolating.

Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by interpolation? Are you trying to get rid of the blurriness (antialiasing) when you oversize the image?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the blurriness (antialiasing).

Comment: Please add more detail to your question in order to get accurate answers.

Comment: I am converting vector/raster files to SVG.  The raster part can be any arbitrary sized pixel-art.  I am want the raster embedded into the final SVG file.  I am looking for the most efficient means to accomplish this.  I can convert the raster to some supported image type (PNG/TIF/JPG) then Encode64 and embed into the SVG.  I am looking for the equivalent of Firefox (image-rendering="-moz-crisp-edges") for IE and other browsers.

Comment: In your particular case, given that the image is so simple, you could also consider turning it into SVG rectangles instead of using the PNG.

Answer (score 3):

SVG has an [image-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) attribute. Unfortunately none of the values guarantees nearest neighbour interpolation - optimizeSpeed is the closest. Firefox supports an additional value -moz-crisp-edges which guarantees nearest neighbour and I think Webkit has -webkit-optimize-contrast which does much the same.

Comment: Thanks.  -moz-crisp-edges is the effect I am looking for... now to get the other browser to work in a similar fashion.

Comment: `image-rendering="pixelated"` is also an option.